# Option to keep the reputation hidden

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Is there an option to keep the reputation blurred out when you're on stackoverflow? I mean, it stays blurred or hidden with an overlay until you hover on it or click it. Because I often have to pair-program or show some stackoverflow answers to my peers and since the header is sticky on top, I have often heard remarks about my reputation. Would be nice to have a feature to have the reputation revealed only when you interact with it.

Comment: Alternative: log out before a pair-programming session starts.

Comment: Related: [an experiment proposal I made on Meta Stack Overflow a while back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367719/experiment-request-temporarily-stop-showing-characteristics-about-a-user-in-the).

Comment: The topbar has the option to be sticky or not sticky. You can adjust this from [your preferences page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) by checking "Disable top bar stickiness".

Comment: I’d hope this is quite a narrow use case and that most developers would realise that reputation on StackOverflow isn’t the be all end all of being a good developer. If your peers are judging you based solely on your reputation and not your performance, find new peers.

Answer (score 9):

It seems like you would draw more remarks wondering why your reputation is being obscured. Still, with the number of places your reputation is displayed across the network, it would be a huge development effort to obscure them all reliably.

Even that aside, the use case to create a setting where users can optionally hide their own reputation from *themselves* (but nobody else) would seem to be so crazy obscure, I can't imagine what that setting would be called, let alone actually *doing* it.

Maybe you can employ some script to do this client-side, but I'm afraid this will almost certainly be [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Comment: makes complete sense. thanks!

Comment: I [proposed an experiment to do this randomly with certain users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367719/experiment-request-temporarily-stop-showing-characteristics-about-a-user-in-the) a while back. What do you think of it?

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a small user script to hide your reputation from the top bar, and only show it upon hover:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Hide Reputation.
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Hide Reputation. 
// @author       Shree (https://stackoverflow.com/users/965146/shree)
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    let $rep = $('.-item').eq(1);
    $rep.css({'opacity': '0'});
    $rep.mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("opacity", "1");
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css("opacity", "0");
    });
})();
```

[Installation Link](https://github.com/sri-shree/Hide-Reputation/raw/master/hidereputation.user.js)